# Code First - Entity Framework - How to expose foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following data object:

```
public class Customer : System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public Customer ()
    {
        // this.HasRequired(a => a.EyeColorType).WithMany().HasForeignKey(a => a.EyeColorTypeID);
    }

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("EyeColorTypeID")]
    public EyeColorType EyeColorType { get; set; }
    // public int EyeColorTypeID { get; set; }

}
```

}

What I am trying to do, is expose the field `EyeColorTypeID` on the generated Customer property, as well as specify the name in the DB.

If I remove both comments, it works, but I would like to use a data annotation for this. Something like `[ExposeForeignKey("EyeColorTypeID")]` and have it all happen automatically.

Is this possible? How would I go about that?

Comment: You need to add `public Int32 EyeColorTypeID` (or whatever data type your key is).

Comment: Thanks I meant to include that. I have added it to the question above now.  Basically I still need that commented out line at the top to actually expose it, so I can say myContext.Customers.First().EyeColorTypeID = 1; Otherwise it will only give me myContext.Customers.First().EyeColorType = someEyeColorTypeInstance; The binding part is fine, I just want the foreign ID field to be exposed

Comment: Maybe you can use PostSharp for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add it to the model and make the navigation property virtual (for lazy loading):

```
public class Customer : //etc
{

   //your stuff

   [Required]
   public int EyeColorTypeID {get; set;}

   public virtual EyeColorType EyeColorType { get; set; }
}
```

The naming conventions of EF will bind the `EyeColorTypeID` to the `EyeColorType` navigation property.

Comment: sorry I missed that out of the original question. I have added it now. Yes I can do that, but I need the top part (commented it out) to expose it on the object. How can I achieve this using ONLY data annotations?

Comment: Which EF version are you using? I never needed to use used `.HasForeignKey` call. On the other hand, I never needed to use the `: EntityTypeConfiguration` as well. For me, a `public int FooId` and a `public VIRTUAL FooClass Foo` was enough.

Comment: version 6. Yes I can just create a class without the interface and just put the property ID in as you suggested, but then it doesnt appear as a property in my class. It blinds it and gives it the right name in the DB, but I can only dot through to the instance and not the ID int

Comment: Maybe you forgot to make it `public`, if the `int` is `public`, it must be in your `class`.