# Query joined tables c# code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, join, code-first

I have these tables i have made in c# using code first approach.

Employee class:

```
public int id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
```

Department class:

```
public int id { get; set; }
public string deptName { get; set; }
public IQueryable<Employee> { get; set; }
```

This generates a DepartmentID in my Employee table in my sql database. I cannot however access this field in c# as DepartmentID is not a field in the employee class/model.

My question is how do i access this variable. I wish to do some various joins etc but am struggling with this.

Comment: Why don't you add that column in the model?

Comment: I kinda figured that since these columns can be auto generated that I would take advantage of it. Is that the only solution ?

Comment: That is the right approach when you want to use EF. There is no point of having a relationship without having declaring a navigation property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly [expose the foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081868/code-first-entity-framework-how-to-expose-foreign-keys), but it is not necessarily needed. The beauty of EF is you don't need joins.

First I would clean up your classes:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Exposed FK. By convention, EF know this is a FK.
    // EF will add one if you omit it.
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }  
    // Navigation properties are how you access the related (joined) data
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }  
}

public class Department
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can query your data easily:

```
var employeeWithDepartment = context.Employee
      .Include(e => e.Department)
      .FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID = 123);

var employeeName = employeeWithDepartment.Name;
var departmentName = employeeWithDepartment.Department.Name;
... etc.

var departmentWithListOfEmployees = context.Departments
     .Include(d => d.Employees)
     .Where(d => d.Name == "Accounting")
     .ToList();

... build table or something
foreach (var employee in departmentWithListOfEmployees.Employees)
{
     <tr><td>@employee.ID</td><td>@employee.Name</td>
}
... close table
```