# Entity Framework detached virtual object after using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have set up an MVC environment where I am taking an Entity Framework entity, mapping it to a DTO for the user to modify and then mapping the DTO back to the EF entity.

My EF classes are as follows:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public virtual StreetAddress Address { get; set; }
    /*More stuff here*/
}
//For the purpose of this example lets assume that addresses cannot be changed, they are read-only
public class StreetAddress
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    /*More stuff here*/
}
```

My DTO is:

```
public class PersonDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public StreetAddress Address { get; set; }
    /*More stuff here*/
}
```

From here I map the Person to a PersonDTO and back again:

```
Person person = /*retrieve from database*/;
PersonDTO dto = Mapper.Map<PersonDTO>(person);

// send dto to user, user updates name, user sends dto back
// the address object is the same, but it might have been converted to JSON or something like that during transport

Person person = Mapper.Map<Person>(dto);
```

So I now have a Person ready to save to the database. The StreetAddress object still has the same information, however now EF sees the Address as detached. I can't use `context.Attach(Address)` because the context already has a StreetAddress with the same Key attached, and attempting to do so causes an exception to be thrown.

If I choose to ignore the detached Address and add this new person to my database, EF sees the Address as a brand new object and inserts it into the database, causing the address row in the database to be duplicated, same details, new ID.

My current solution is to replace the Address object with the one that is already attached to the context:

```
var tracked = context.ChangeTracker.Entries<Address>();
person.Address = tracked.Where(x => x.Entity.Id == person.AddressId).Select(e => e.Entity).FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there a better way to do this? perhaps a way to tell EF that if there is a Person with an Address where the Address ID is already in the database there is no need to insert it?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to [expose your FK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081868/code-first-entity-framework-how-to-expose-foreign-keys) `AddressId` in Person and PersonDTO.

Another is to set the entity state to modified: `context.Entry(person.Address).State = EntityState.Modified;` as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state)

Comment: I actually already have the foreign key exposed, that's where the `/*addressId*/` comment came from, I have edited the question to make that more clear.

How can I use the exposed foreign key to help me here?

Comment: I also tried to change the state of the person.Address, but it failed with the exception `Attaching an entity of type '.....StreetAddress' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value`

Comment: Is this MVC? What is your save logic? I personally find it easiest to just populate my ViewModel in the GET and send it to the view, then on POST I fetch the object back and map the changed viewmodel fields back in before saving.

Comment: Yes it is MVC, as for the save logic, I am quite new to EF, but for this specific case I am just using `context.Set<Person>().Add(person);context.SaveChanges();` as the stripped down version of my code currently only inserts new Persons.

Comment: Try nulling out the Address navigation property (or ignoring it when mapping DTO to entity), but make sure AddressID is set.

Comment: Nulling out the Address seems to work, but what if Address is no longer read only and I now want to change the StreetName? I guess what I am looking for is some sort of "AttachAndReplaceExisting" where EF overwrites the existing attached (by primary key) StreetAddress instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: What I do is create a pretty flat view model (street name at parent level). Auto mapper is great for mapping child property to DTO. Then on POST, I fetch the parent and child together and map DTO back into the object graph. EF handles all the rest.