# c# .NET 4.8 How to create multi column index using default foreign keys on existing entity in DatabaseContext.cs

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using .NET 4.8. I have 3 tables: TableA, TableB and TableC. TableA has foreign key relationships already set up to TableB and TableC. This was done using a code first migration.

This is the code for TableA:

```
public class TableA : Entity<int>
{
    public bool SomeColumn1 { get; set; }
    public bool SomeColumn2 { get; set; }
    public bool SomeColumn3 { get; set; }

    public virtual TableB TableB { get; set; }
    
    public virtual TableC TableC { get; set; }
}
```

So in my db TableA has the columns `TableB_Id` and `TableC_Id` that relate back to their respective tables.

I want to add a unique index to TableA such that the combination of `TableB_Id` and `TableC_Id` is unique.

I want to do this in my `DatabaseContext.cs` file using the FLUENT pattern. I added this to my `DatabaseContext.cs` in the `OnModelCreating()` method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TableA>().HasIndex(a => new { a.TableB, a.TableC }).IsUnique();
```

(`a.TableB` and `a.TableC` are the only options available when I enter `a.` )

I then compile my solution and try to create a migration but I get an error that says

> Sequence contains no matching element

I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081868/code-first-entity-framework-how-to-expose-foreign-keys) that suggests to add values in the base entity, so I changed my code for TableA to this:

```
public class TableA : Entity<int>
{
    public bool SomeColumn1 { get; set; }
    public bool SomeColumn2 { get; set; }
    public bool SomeColumn3 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index("IX_TableBAndTableC", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public int TableB_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual TableB TableB { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public int TableC_Id { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_TableBAndTableC", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public virtual TableC TableC { get; set; }
}
```

and `TableB_Id` and `TableC_Id` are now available in my code in `DatabaseContext.cs` but when I compile the solution and create a migration it drops the existing `TableB_Id` and `TableC_Id` columns on TableA and replaces them with `TableB_Id1` and `TableC_Id1` and then creates the index.

I then found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061378/how-to-expose-foreign-key-property-to-existing-entity-having-navigational-proper) that suggests to add a foreign key decorator to the base entity so I commented out the code in my `DatabaseContext.cs` file and changed my code in my TableA entity to be this:

```
public class TableA : Entity<int>
{
    public bool SomeColumn1 { get; set; }
    public bool SomeColumn2 { get; set; }
    public bool SomeColumn3 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TableB_Id")]
    public virtual TableB TableB { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("TableC_Id")]
    public virtual TableC TableC { get; set; }
}
```

but when I compile the solution and generate a migration the migration is empty with nothing in the `up()` and `down()` methods.

I searched in the official documentation but was not able to find anything that specifically instructed on how to create a multi column unique index using the default columns that get created when I set up the foreign keys using a code first migration (`TableA.TableB_Id` and `TableA.TableC_Id`). The columns `TableA.TableB_Id` and `TableA.TableC_Id` are created by the entity framework automatically so I am not able to use them directly in my `DatabaseContext.cs` file.

Please can someone give me some help in figuring out how to create a multi column unique index on these two default foreign keys `TableB_Id` and `TableC_Id` by either adding something to the `DatabaseContext.cs` file or the base entity code for TableA, or both.

A correct, clearly explained answer will be marked as accepted and upvoted. Thanks.

Comment: I might be wrong here, but I believe you need indexes on the actual (likely int or guid) columns named `TableB_Id` and `TableC_Id`, not the `TableB` and `TableC` object references.

Comment: @TN that's right, but when I try to type `a.` in `DatabaseContext.cs` the values `TableB_Id` and `TableC_Id` are not available, and they're not available because those values aren't specifically declared in the entity code for `TableA`, those fields are the default fields that the entity framework comes up with when the code first migration is run. That's the big question, is how do I make `TableB_Id` and `TableC_Id` available as fields I can use in `DatabaseContext.cs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with it I found [this page](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/entity-framework/ef-data-annotations-foreignkey-attribute/) that talks about foreign key relationships in entity framework. This is where I found a different way to format my code for my `TableA` entity that will accomplish what I need to do.

So here is the code for my `TableA` entity:

```
public class TableA : Entity<int>
{
    public bool SomeColumn1 { get; set; }
    public bool SomeColumn2 { get; set; }
    public bool SomeColumn3 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TableB")]
    public int TableB_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual TableB TableB { get; set; }
        
    [ForeignKey("TableC")]
    public int TableC_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual TableC TableC { get; set; }
}
```

This is very similar to one approach I tried in my original post, I just had a few things not set up right.

After I added this code to my `TableA` entity, back in my `DatabaseCOntext.cs` file I was able to add this line in the `OnModelCreating()` method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TableA>().HasIndex(a => new { a.TableB_Id, a.TableC_Id }).IsUnique();
```

which is now pointed at the fields `TableA.TableB_Id` and `TableA.TableC_Id` which weren't available before.

I compiled my solution and created a new migration and it appeared like it was going to do everything I needed it to.

I compiled the solution again and ran the migrations and the columns `TableA.TableB_Id` and `TableA.TableC_Id` are still present, set up as foreign keys to their respective tables and there is a unique constraint on them that will not allow duplicate rows to be inserted.

I hope this is helpful to others. If what I did is not clear, please leave a comment and I'll do my best to clarify.